# SQL Table causes slow running Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, performance

I have a sql table that has approximately 6,000 records with 17 columns each.  If I do a basic search on the table (i.e. Select * from table_Orders)... it takes 1.5 minutes to return all the records!  Any query that I run using this table is also very slow.  I have reindexed the table so fragmentation is not an issue.  This table has 2 nvarchar(max) columns in it that is storing xml data.  Returning the table without these columns is extremely fast (less than 1 second).  So, i'm guessing it's the xml data that is bogging down the queries.  Is there anything I can do to speed up performance of queries that utilize columns with xml in them?  Any insight will be greatly appreciated.  I don't typically work with xml within sql, so I don't even know where to start.

Comment: The issue is simply the size of the columns.  You can extract information from them (even using indexes).  Or, don't return them at all.

Comment: Since `(MAX)` data type can stored upto 2GB of data and you clearly have a decent amount of data stored in these columns hence the poor performance with these columns, I would simply put them in a Separate table (using foregin keys). You cannot index (max) data types so dont waste your resources by adding unnecessary indexes.

Comment: I'm interested to know why those columns are `nvarchar` if this is XML data.  XML is a sub-set of ascii -- there is no reason to use anything besides UTF-8.  You should probably change them to `varchar(max)`

Comment: What kind of **clustered index** do you have on this table (if any)?

Comment: Note: design changes are NOT an answer to this question.

Comment: Lots of good info received.  I have inherited this database which was built by consultants.  I wouldn't put that amount of data in an varchar column either.  I think I will try separating the data into a different table.  I was just hoping their was some optimizing technique that I didn't know about.

Comment: It's using 1 index.  PK Clustered index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like network speed and NOT search times. Even a table scan of 6000 rows only takes a fraction of a second - to search all the rows. Returning those rows to a client though... you're downloading all that data, so you're going to see a difference when you retrieve a lot of it. This has nothing to do with "query performance" and there isn't anything you can do about it unless you can make the network faster or deliver less data.

You can test this by issuing queries searching for a key in your clustered index. Assuming you have a clustered index on RowID...

```
select RowId, NonXmlColumn where RowId = 3 -- or some other reasonable key
select RowId, XmlColumn where RowId = 3
```

The search time for those queries will be the same. So, any difference in speed can be attributed to the network.

Comment: We may have a networking issue.  I have tried two queries:<br/> `select Id, NonXmlColumn from table_Orders where autonumber > 3000<br/>
select Id, XmlColumn from table_Orders where autonumber > 3000`  <br/>The first query ran in 1 second... the second query took 1 minute to run.

Comment: And what was the result of that? Remember this test is only valid if you have an index on "autonumber" field, that does not "cover" other fields.

Comment: hmmm... Ok... i adjusted the queries to search on the index field.  There was only a 3 second difference between the results.  Does this mean i should index my xml column?

Comment: Look at the query plans of each one to see if theres a difference. Both queries should be two steps: a clustered index SEEK, and a SELECT. If they both look like that, then yes, the only thing affecting the time is the size of the data being returned, and indexing will not help. The query is going as fast as it can, and your bottleneck is the network.

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Jasmine .  It may be a networking issue, which is definitely out of the realm of my knowledge.  I will let our networking team know the findings.  For now, i'll work on moving the xml data that i need into a different table format.

Comment: It's not a network "issue" it's a fact of life. It takes time to download data.

Answer (score 0):

I would not store that data in a table. I would not store in `VARCHAR` if I did. Not to sound like a jerk.

SQL Server has a `xml` datatype: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx
It says there is limitations. You should see what applies to your scenario.

If you need to preserve the XML - stick it somewhere else and pull from it what ever fields you'll need to search on.